# Static methods usages and warning level in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2013, static-methods

I have a simple code like below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<string> test = t => Console.WriteLine(t);
    var str = new[] { "hello", "world", "2.0" };
    str.ForEach(test);
}
```

VS2013 complains about it, as "ForEach" is a static method of Array, the right way should have been:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action<string> test = t => Console.WriteLine(t);
    var str = new[] { "hello", "world", "2.0" };
    Array.ForEach(str, test);
}
```

However, it didn't complain on my coworker's VS2013.

So I figure, there is somewhere in VS's options that decrease the error level to warning so that the first code snippet can pass, which happens to be the default of my coworker's.

Can anyone confirm and show me where to change?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `var str = new string[] { "value1", "value2", etc, };`? The ForEach will depend on the runtime.

Comment: @ManoDestra you can emit the `String` in this case

Comment: @ManoDestra no the type is redundant as the compiler can infer it from the content. You don't need to specify it explicitly

Comment: Thanks, guys. Must be a fairly recent feature, I guess.

Comment: There's a `ForEach` defined on `List<T>` that isn't static.  Also the coworker might have an extension method `ForEach` they are using.

Comment: _"So I figure, there is somewhere in VS's options that decrease the error level to warning so that the first code snippet can pass"_ - what? No. Why? Does it _run_ on your colleague's machine? Just hit F12 on `ForEach` to go to its definition and your question is solved.

Comment: @ManoDestra It's not recent. I think it's been around since C# 3

Comment: Don't know how I missed that one then! A little too implicit for my liking, but thanks anyway :D

Comment: My coworker have exactly the same code like mine.

Comment: Do your coworkers have the same list of "using <namespace>" ?